# “Ankaŭ” ĉe la fino de frazo

Tags: grammar

Mi lernis ke oni ĝenerale devus meti la vorton *ankaŭ* antaŭ la afero kiun ĝi koncernas. Tamen mi ofte vidas ĝin ĉe la fino de frazo. Oni povas trovi kelkajn ekzemplojn de tio en la Tekstaro:

> Se ŝi ne permesas, li iras **ankaŭ**.
>
> La komercegisto sin levis **ankaŭ**.

Mi trovis en [PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/e-vortecaj_vortetoj/ceteraj/ankau.html#i-vb4) ke oni foje povas meti *ankaŭ* post substantivo kiun ĝi koncernas se tio helpas la stilon. Tamen en ĉi tiuj ekzemploj, la vorto estas tute ĉe la fino de la frazo kaj ne proksimas substantivon.

Ĉu tio estas bona stilo? Ĉu estas regulo pri tio, kion la vorto koncernas? Ekzemple, ĉu ĝi koncernas la tutan frazon aŭ la subjekton?

Answer (score 6):

Laŭ PMEG ne estas multaj reguloj. Mi sugestas uzi ĝin antaŭ la aferon, kiun ĝi koncernas. Tio, laŭ mi estas la regulo, eĉ kiam *ankaŭ* troviĝas ĉe fino.

*ankaŭ* fine de frazo uzeblas kiam estas subkomprenata frazo, kiu sekvus, kiun oni ne volas ripeti aŭ kiu estas tute evidenta. Ĝi plu staras antaŭ la koncerna afero (eliziita). Ekzemple (el Tekstaro):

```
La vizaĝon de Nikola mi memoras, lian frazon ankaŭ [memoras mi].
Mi kvietiĝis, la knabo ankaŭ [kvietiĝis].
```

Oni povas uzi ĝin fine ankaŭ kiam ĝi fakte rilatas pli *tamen* ol *ankaŭ*. Tio okazas kiam estas neado en la koncerna afero. Via unua supra frazo montras tion:

```
Se ŝi ne permesas, li iras ankaŭ.
```

aŭ

```
Se ŝi ne permesas [akompani/iri] li tamen iras.
```

En aliaj okazoj mi rekomendas sekvi la regulon, meti ĝin ĉiam antaŭ la koncernan aferon. Kial? Ĉar tio estas kohera kaj do komprenebla de ĉiuj (mislokita *ankaŭ* kelkfoje spegulas uzadon en la denaskaj lingvoj kaj do estas tuj komprenebla nur de tiuj lingvanoj).

```
ankaŭ Eva manĝis en la ĝardeno.
```

Tio signifas ke iu(j) manĝis en la ĝardeno, kaj Eva akompanis tiu(j)n.

```
Eva ankaŭ manĝis en la ĝardeno.
```

Eva faris ion alian en la ĝardeno, eble ludi, diskuti,... *kaj* ankaŭ manĝi

```
Eva manĝis ankaŭ en la ĝardeno.
```

Ŝi manĝas en pluraj ejoj, ankaŭ en la la ĝardeno

```
Eva manĝis en la ĝardeno ankaŭ.
```

Por mi, tiu lasta frazo, izolita, estas evitinda.

Comment: Mi opinias, ke tio estas tre bona respondo. Mi ne scias, kiel aliaj lingvoj estas regulata (ĉina, hinda, ...). Sed verŝajne estas natura konsidero, ke vortoj kio staras proksime unu la alian apartenas unu al la alian.

Answer (score 1):

Bona demando!

En ĉi tiu kazo, mi uzas tiun saman regulon kiu troviĝas en la italan, koncerne la vorton "anche" (elparolata "anke").

Kutime (fakte, preskaŭ ĉiam), oni metas la vorto "anche" antaŭ la koncernenda vorto.

Tamen, itala instruistino iam mi diris ke oni povas ankaŭ diri "Lui c'era anche" anstataŭ "Anche lui c'era" (Esperante: "Li ĉeestis ankaŭ" anstataŭ "Ankaŭ li ĉeestis").

Grave scii ke ŝi diris tion pri la itala, sed ĉar la esperanta vorto "ankaŭ" similas al la itala vorto "anche", mi pensus ke Zamenhof aprobus uzi esperanta "ankaŭ" kiel itala "anche".  Do, laŭ mi, oni provu uzi "ankaŭ" kutime antaŭ la koncernenda vorto (antaŭ la "pria" vorto), sed ne malbonas kiam "ankaŭ" estas uzata ĉe la fino de la frazo.